# Int, Char, Object Datatypes using [==] operator & .Equals()

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I'm confused on this code what is the difference between the two conditions? Why the results are not the same? 
***`Example Number 1`*** - Don't have the same `datatype` w/ same value, but it returns the same result of **`true`**

```
 int value1 = 'a';
 char value2 ='a'; 
 Console.WriteLine(value1 == value2);
 Console.WriteLine(value1.Equals(value2));
```

***`Example Number 2`*** - They have the same `datatype` w/ same value, but it returns **`false & true`**

```
object obj1 = "Object One";
object obj2 = new string("Object One".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(obj1 == obj2);
Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));
```

Comment: `int` and `char` have some magic support in the compiler, which is why whatever is allowed between those isn't representable for anything else.

Comment: Put simply, there's actually a lot going on in your seemingly simple code that warrants quite a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's actually a lot going on in the seemingly simple code in your question so let's deal with it one step at a time. Please note that there is so much going on that I might miss something, use the comment field.

First piece of code first:

```
int value1 = 'a';
char value2 ='a'; 
Console.WriteLine(value1 == value2);
Console.WriteLine(value1.Equals(value2));
```

This line:

```
int value1 = 'a';
```

should give you a hint about what the reason for the behavior of this code is. There is a silent conversion from a `char` to an `int`. In fact, what is compiled doesn't mention a `char` at all for this variable, it's a number. The number assigned to the `int` variable is the codepoint value of `a`, which is 97.

The first comparison:

```
value1 == value2
```

is done using the `==` operator on `int`, so in reality, a pure numeric comparison is done, as though the character is a number. The same silent conversion takes place here, the character is converted to a number. Since it is the same character and the same conversion, it stands to reason that you end up with 97 from this comparison as well.

[This is mentioned in the spec under section 6.1.2, Implicit numeric conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table):

> The implicit numeric conversions are:
>   ...
>   From `char` to `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`, or `decimal`

That means that what is written is actually equivalent to:

```
97 == 97
```

The second comparison:

```
value1.Equals(value2)
```

is done using the exact same conversion, so you have:

```
97.Equals(97)
```

So let's make the first piece of code super-clear by adding explicit casts and changing the code to be what the compiler sees:

```
// int value1 = (int)'a';                        // 97
int value1 = 97;
char value2 = 'a';
Console.WriteLine(value1 == (int)value);         // 97 == 97
Console.WriteLine(value1.Equals((int)value2));   // 97.Equals(97);
```

I also asked [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) to show me the decompilation of these two statements:

```
int a = 97;
int a = 'a';
```

And they both compile to:

```
ldc.i4.s 61             // 0x61 = 97
```

So just to be clear, this silent conversion is done *by the compiler*, there is no runtime code that converts the character to an int for the *declaration*, the code executes and is compiled as though you had actually written

```
int value1 = 97;
```

So that is the reason for this part.

Now on to the next part:

```
object obj1 = "Object One";
object obj2 = new string("Object One".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(obj1 == obj2);
Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));
```

Here you are first declaring two `object` variables, this is important, and then give them the same `string` *value*, although they are two distinct *instances*.

So let's deal with the first comparison:

```
obj1 == obj2
```

This is done using the `==` operator defined for `object`, which compares *references*. Since we've already established that your funky string construction for the second variable constructs a new instance, the reference comparison indicates that they are different.

The reason why it is is using the `==` operator defined on `object`, and not the on defined on `string` is because operators are *resolved* at compile-time and at compile-time the compiler only knows that the variables are of type `object`. The fact that they contain strings, even the fact that the compiler could "see" that you've just assigned strings to them, so that it should use the `string` `==` operator instead, is ignored.

However, when you do this:

```
obj1.Equals(obj2)
```

Then you are calling the *virtual* `.Equal(object other)` declared in `object`, **which is *overridden* in `string`**, and thus you get string *content* comparison, which indicates they are the same.

So let's make the second piece of code super-clear as well:

```
object obj1 = "Object One";
object obj2 = new string("Object One".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(obj1.ReferenceEquals(obj2));          // <-- changed
Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Example 1, int and char are value types so the equality comparison (via == or Equals) defaults to bit by bit comparison (as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)) as none of them overrides == and their Equals implementation delegates the work to ==.

true is returned in both cases because value1 and value2 have the same binary representation.

In Example 2, string is a reference type, obj1 and obj2 are references to 2 string instances which happen to have the same content.

But since they are declared as object, and == is resolved at compile time, the only option for the compiler is to emit a reference comparison (=false)

In contrast, obj1.Equals will actually be a call to `string.Equals(object)` which will return the comparison of the string values

Answer (score 1):

***`Example1`***

`int` has value of `97` and so does the `char`. (see [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange#ASCII-Tabelle))
Both are Value types, so the value gets compared everytime.

***`Example2`***

strings are reference types.
so using `.Equals` compares the values (wich are the same) and `==` compares the reference, wich is diffrent.

Comment: It's probably the opposite since == is statically resolved and a reference comparison will be used, whereas Equals is dynamically resolved

Comment: Example2: but the values are the same but the result on it is true & false using the "==" & .equals() , what' the difference?

Comment: It isn't as simple as "the value gets compared everytime", char and int have magic support by the compiler which makes them behave different from other comparisons. If you create two structs with an int, which are also two value types, using `==` will have to be specifically implemented and thus whatever `==` is doing is completely up to the programmer.

Comment: Anybody may feel free to edit my answer if I got anything wrong here :)

Comment: @Squirrelintraining In short, in example 2, == will compare the references since the compiler does not know that obj1 and obj2 are strings, and operators are resolved statically (at compile time) unlike Equals which will be resolved dynamically at run time and since obj1 and obj2 are actually strings, it's their values that are going to be compared. I think the OP inverted the 2 results.

Comment: @vc74 yeah he inverted it. I ran the code in the interactive shell and the result spewed out the other way around. I've eddited my answer

Comment: @Squirrelintraining It's the OP who actually inverted them in the first place ;). BTW it's not because string is a reference type that == compares the references but because the variables are declared as `object`. If they had been declared as strings, the result would have been true.

Answer (score 0):

Example Number 1

Here [Implicit Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#implicit-conversions) was happened and since both are value types, not references are compared which results to true. To break it further down, this is what happened:

```
int value1 = 'a';           //First converts to ASCII value 97 and then stored in value1
char value2 ='a';           //Stored as a
Console.WriteLine(value1);  //output is 97
Console.WriteLine(value2);  //output is a
Console.WriteLine(value1 == value2);   //compares using implicit conversion. Since value type, so only value comparison and hence true 
Console.WriteLine('a' == 97);          //compares using implicit conversion.  Since value type, so only value comparison and hence true  
Console.WriteLine(value1.Equals(value2)); //compares using implicit conversion.  Since value type, so only value comparison and hence true
```

Example Number 2 -

Here, you have manually used the conversion from Char to String, so [Explicit Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) takes place. To break it further, this is what happened:

```
object obj1 = "Object One";     //string value is stored in Object type variable
object obj2 = new string("Object One".ToCharArray());  //Explicit conversion
Console.WriteLine(obj1);        //Output is Object One
Console.WriteLine(obj2);        //Output is Object One
Console.WriteLine(obj1 == obj2);  //Since == compares both reference and value, hence the false output
Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2));  //Equals() compares just the value, hence the true result
```